# Getting error in telerik push notification for android

Tags: android, push-notification, telerik

I am trying to implement push notification for my hybrid application using telerik platform. It is working fine for iOS. But in android, its getting an error - "Push notifications are currently initializing". 
This is the code that I have used.

```
app.everlive = new Everlive({
  appId: "xxxxxxx",
  scheme: 'http'
});
var enablePushNotifications = function() {
  var devicePushSettings = {
    iOS: {
        badge: 'true',
        sound: 'true',
        alert: 'true'
    },
    android: {
        senderID: 'xxxxxxx'
    },
    wp8: {
        channelName: 'EverlivePushChannel'
    },
    notificationCallbackIOS: onPushNotificationReceived,
    notificationCallbackAndroid: onPushNotificationReceived,
    notificationCallbackWP8: onPushNotificationReceived
  };
app.everlive.push.currentDevice().enableNotifications(devicePushSettings,     successCallback, errorCallback);
 function onPushNotificationReceived(e) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(e));
};

function successCallback(e) {
    app.everlive.push.register(devicePushSettings, function() {
        alert("Successful registration in Backend Services. You are ready to receive push notifications.");
    }, function(err) {
        alert("Error: " + err.message);
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(e));
};

function errorCallback(e) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(e));
  };
};
```

Its going to errorCallback. Could any one please help me out with this? Thanks in advance.